# Webpack config to vite config

Tags: javascript, webpack, config, vite

I'm upgrading from a Webpack build to a Vite build for my application. I'm currently stuck trying to inject a number of links into each page. Part of my Webpack config looks like this:

```js
const entries = {
   index: [
      'src/pages/index.ts',
      '@webcomponents/bundle,
      'whatwg-fetch',
      'core-js/stable',
     ],
   login: [
      'src/pages/login.ts',
      '@webcomponents/bundle,
      'whatwg-fetch',
      'core-js/stable',
     ],   
   about: [
      'src/pages/about.ts',
      '@webcomponents/bundle,
      'whatwg-fetch',
      'core-js/stable',
     ],
   contact: [
      'src/pages/contact.ts',
      '@webcomponents/bundle,
      'whatwg-fetch',
      'core-js/stable',
     ],
}
```

In Webpack Im passing this file into the **entry** property in the webpack.config.js file. After converting it to Javascript, it injects the *@webcomponents/bundle*, *whatwg-fetch*, and *core-js/stable* links into each ts file.

```
module.exports = {
  entry : entries,
  ...
}
```

I haven't figured out how to duplicate this with Vite since its entry point doesn't allow the object's keys to be arrays. Here is what I have so far:

```
const entries = {
  index: 'src/pages/index.html',
  login: 'src/pages/login.html',
  about: 'src/pages/about.html,
  contact: 'src/pages/contact/html
}
```

These HTML files have a script tag with src to the ts file.
Im passing entries into the vite.config.js file rollupOption.input:

```
export default defineConfig({
   build: {
     outDir: 'dist',
     rollupOptions: {
        input: entries
     }
   }
})
```

This is just a part of the Webpack config which is very complex and I'm relatively new to this.

##### So how would I inject the *@webcomponents/bundle*, *whatwg-fetch*, and *core-js/stable* links into each page without doing it manually?